# How to fix "[WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying..."

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, nunit, warnings

Recently we have added another test agent to run our automated selenium tests on Azure DevOps, and this warning has been appearing in the testAssemblies logs.

"[1559090506.462][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
2019-05-29T00:41:50.5981818Z [1559090510.598][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying..."

All solutions I've looked at say that that it is an issue with the chrome driver version, however we are running the same version on both agents and only getting it on the new agent, we have tried changing versions and not had any luck.

Here is what the logs say on the old agent.

> Starting test execution, please wait...
> NUnit Adapter 3.13.0.0: Test execution started
> Running all tests in C:\agents\agent01_work\r1\a\QA.Automation.Hub\drop\Shakeout\UITests\bin\Release\UITests.dll
>
> NUnit3TestExecutor converted 114 of 114 NUnit test cases
> Starting ChromeDriver 74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}) on port 58738
>
> Only local connections are allowed.
> Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious

and here is what the logs say on running on the new agent.

> Starting test execution, please wait...
> NUnit Adapter 3.13.0.0: Test execution started
> Running all tests in C:\agents\agent01_work\r1\a\QA.Automation.Hub\drop\Shakeout\UITests\bin\Release\UITests.dll
>
> NUnit3TestExecutor converted 114 of 114 NUnit test cases
> Starting ChromeDriver 74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}) on port 50013
>
> Only local connections are allowed.
> Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
>
> [1559090506.462][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...
> [1559090510.598][WARNING]: Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...

any information on what could cause this warning would be appreciated. cheers

Comment: Update the question removing the `<blockquotes>` from the errors and provide the entire error trace logs?

Comment: Any luck? I think I'm having the same issue.

Comment: I had the same issue 'Timed out connecting to Chrome, retrying...' it seems intermittent to me.